# What does it mean take the determinant of the Jacobian in: $ V_{k+1} = \int_{M_{k}} \Bigg\vert det(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}) \Bigg\vert dx$

Tags: calculus, analysis, dynamical-systems

In this [Lecture](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0111177v1.pdf), in the subsection **Evolution of Volumes** tell us:

> Let $M \subset D$ be a compat subset of phase space. We can define its volume by a usual Riemann integral:
>   $$
> Vol(M) = \int_{M}dx, \hspace{3mm} dx = dx_{1} \dots dx_{n}
> $$
>   We can define the sets $M_{k} = F^{k}(M)$, we assume that $F$ is continuously differentiable: $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x)$, the Jacobian matrix of $F$ at $x$, which is the $n \times n$ matrix.
>
> Assume $F$ is diffeomorphism and let $V_{k} = Vol(M_{k})$. Then
>   $$
> V_{k+1} = \int_{M_{k}} \Bigg\vert det(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x})\Bigg\vert dx
> $$

My question is: What does it mean take the determinant of the Jacobian and what is the proof about it?, What happen if instead I take the Hessian, what change?

Answer (score 0):

Jacobian at a point is a matrix (with entries from $\mathbb{R}$), you can take a determinant of it, what puzzles you? If you take Hessian instead you will get something completely different -- it is easy to see if you take $F$ to be a linear map -- then the Hessian is just zero, whereas Jacobian is not.

To the formula it you basically split your $M$ into many small pieces, such that in every one of them your map is almost linear (looks line a Jacobian around at a point), for linear maps it is very easy to understand how does the volume change under the map, then just take a sum. Proof with details you can find in any standard calculus book.